# Use Python social auth to only get tokens

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

I am using the fantastic [Python social auth](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/) with `Django`.
However, at the moment, everytime the process is invoked, a new user is created. I only need the tokens (`access_token` and `refresh_token`) from the process. How can this be achieved? Via some sort of pipeline?

This is my `pipeline.py` code at the moment (abbreviated):

```
def get_token(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):

    # get token from the oauth2 flow
    social = user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2')
    access_token = social.extra_data['access_token']
    refresh_token = social.extra_data.get('refresh_token')
```

And the corresponding `settings.py` file:

```
# set django session
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

# psa settings
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'

# see http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/settings.html
SOCIAL_AUTH_UUID_LENGTH = 32

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    #'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    #'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'youtube.pipeline.get_token',
)
```

Comment: *"...everytime the process is invoked, a new user is created..."* - what process?

Comment: @xyres: The process of authenticating a user towards Google+ or Facebook or Twitter. It gets started with a link in the template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's all in the pipeline. If you take a look at what you already have, you'll even see the `social.pipeline.user.create_user` step.

[From the documentation](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/pipeline.html#authentication-pipeline):

> ```
> # Create a user account if we haven't found one yet.
> 'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
> ```

([source for that function](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/pipeline/user.py#L58))

Replace this (and all of the following steps if you don't need them) with whatever it is that you are trying to achieve.

```
def get_token(backend, uid, *args, **kwargs):
    # get token from the oauth2 flow
    provider = backend.name
    social = backend.strategy.storage.user.get_social_auth(provider, uid)
    access_token = social.extra_data['access_token']
    refresh_token = social.extra_data.get('refresh_token')
```

The modified method should work even if no user exists/is created.

Comment: I go and try this.

Comment: I get an error that the `uid` is not defined - how do I get this one?

Comment: Ah, sorry, looks like [`uid` is one of the arguments to the function](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/pipeline/social_auth.py#L18) (created by the `social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid` step). Updated post.

Comment: The `social` object cannot be found (it's always `None`) - additionally the `extra_data` gets initialized later in the pipeline queue. What's wrong there?

Comment: The code given only works (ie. the `social` object can only be found) when the user has been created. Neverthess, thanks for the effort put in.